# Cannot create links to some allauth files which I changed

Tags: django, django-allauth

I customized the 'allauth' password_reset and password_change files and my file structure looks like:

Templates

_account

____login

____logout

____password_reset

____password_change

The problem is I cannot create links to those two files (but I can create links to the other files in the same folder.

For example:

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
```

works, but

```
<a href="{% url 'account_password_reset' %}">Reset Password</a>
```

doesn't.

The error I get is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Reverse for 'account_password_reset' not found.
'account_password_reset' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I've tried a lot of things but just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'account_password_reset' %}">Reset Password</a>
```

instead of that use

```
<a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Reset Password</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was Googling this and couldn't find anything on it. Do you mind very briefly explaining why that works?

Comment: you can check it on github https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html